# symfony 2.5 use ClassLoader to add Zend_pdf

Tags: symfony, classloader, zend-pdf

I'm working in Symfony 2.5 and want to use the zend framework for pdf (zend_pdf)

I tried the classloader but I probably do something wrong because it doesn't work (of course)...

I don't know where to add my classloader... I thought in autoload.php but I would not know how... this is my autoload.php, the standard one:

```
<?php
 use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
 use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader; 
/**
* @var ClassLoader $loader
*/
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

I tried adding it in my controller like this:

```
 use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassLoader;

/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function pdfAction()
{
    $loader = new ClassLoader();
    $loader->addPrefix('Zend', __DIR__.'/vendor/zf/library');
    $loader->register();

    $pdf = new \Zend\Pdf\Zend_Pdf();
    ....
```

But then he says:

> Attempted to load class "Zend_Pdf" from namespace "Zend\Pdf".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

How do I solve this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should register new namespace for it

I have follow solution to connect zf library

1) zf library is located at vendor/gamma/zf/library

2) venvodor/zf/composer.json

```
{
        "name": "gamma/zf",
        "type": "symfony-bundle",
        "autoload": { 
                        "psr-0": { "Zend_": "" }
                    },
        "target-dir": "",           
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.3",
            "symfony/symfony": "~2.1"
        }
 }
```

3) app/autoload.php

```
    <?php
    use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

    $loader = include __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
    $loader->add("Zend_", __DIR__.'/../vendor/gamma/zf/library');
set_include_path(__DIR__.'/../vendor/gamma/zf/library'.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
```

4) make composer update to generate new namespace

5) use at service/controller as

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\SomeBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

use Zend_XmlRpc_Client;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $cookiePath)
{
...
$this->xmlRpc = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client($zendUrl->getUri(), $server);
...
}
```

Comment: thanks, for making it clear! it worked, i added 
      set_include_path( __DIR__.'/../vendor/zend/library/:../application/classes/:../application/classes/excpetions/:../application/forms/');
because i used zf1 and there where problems with the namespaces.